# Why do I always have to press the alert dialog button twice to close the dialog?

Tags: android, onclick, android-alertdialog

The below alert dialog requires me to click whichever button I click twice in order to close the dialog window and after an hours googling, I can't find the answer. I am sure it is staring me in the face but I just can't see it.

Edit: More searching has led me to believe the dialog is actually opened twice and it is occuring here: 
asset_id_text_view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

```
            showAssetIDDialog();
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Edit: started out with dialog.dismiss(); and some googling suggested trying dialog.cancel(); Neither of which were successful for me.

```
public void showAssetIDDialog() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            CreateTicketActivity.this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Enter Asset ID");

    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true).setMessage(
            "How would you like to proceed?");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Enter text",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //enterTextDialog();
                    dialog.cancel();        

                }
            });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like the problem was indeed with the OnTouchListener

The code was doing what I had asked it to do and that was to open an AlertDialog every time there was a motionEvent. That makes at least 2 times for every touch

by including a switch statement, I was able to only trigger the opening of the alertDialog when the screen was pressed and not also when the screen was released as follows:

```
    asset_id_text_view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                showAssetIDDialog();
                break; 
            default: 
                break;
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

`cancel()` - Cancel the dialog. This is essentially the same as calling dismiss(), but it will also call your DialogInterface.OnCancelListener (if registered).

just cancel() will cancel the listener registerred on DialogInterface.

`dismiss()` - Dismiss this dialog, removing it from the screen. This method can be invoked safely from any thread. Note that you should not override this method to do cleanup when the dialog is dismissed, instead implement that in onStop().

Use `dialog.dismiss()` for your solution

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DismissingADialog

Please refer the above link for further query.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `dialog.dismiss()` in the `OnClickListener` of the buttons to close the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dialog.dismiss();`

> Dismiss this dialog, removing it from the screen. This method can be
>   invoked safely from any thread.

```
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Enter text",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //enterTextDialog();
                 dialog.dismiss();        

            }
        });
```